# How can I pass free object when launching other application by openURL in iOS?

Tags: ios, openurl

I'd like to pass **free and multiple objects** when I launch my application(MyApp2) from another my application(MyApp1) by using `openURL`.

If you know the implementation method, please let me know.

If I could pass `Dictionary` type object, I think I can include free objects in it.

First I've considered using `DocumentInteractionController` but I dropped it because `DocumentInteractionController` **can not** open application directly.

It just show candidate appliation and user need to select application to open.

Thank you.

Comment: Anything you want to pass needs to be encoded into the URL you are opening

Answer (score 0):

You can share the NSUserDefaults between 2 apps.
You will need to enable App Groups on Both projects and define a group.
Then you will be able to access the NSUserDefaults from both apps.

You use the NSUserDefaults with your group id.

```
NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "your group id")
```

Then simply store the data before you send the user to the second app. and read it when it launches.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know we can share all information with `App Groups`. Now I don't want to use it, I'd like to pass objects when launching another application without using `App Groups`.